# Stop playing sound when other element was clicked

Tags: jquery

I cannot deal with probably simple issue. I've got several divs with html5 videos by default muted. While clicked sounds starts to play, while clicked second time it gets muted. But when sound is on and I click on another div with video class it does not stop. How can I stop playing sound of a video while another video is clicked?

```
<div class="v1">
  <video class="video" width="800" height="450" autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="..." type="video/mp4">  
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>

<div class="v2">
  <video class="video" width="800" height="450" autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="..." type="video/mp4">  
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>

<div class="v3">
  <video class="video" width="800" height="450" autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="..." type="video/mp4">  
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>

$(".video").click(function() {
    if (this.muted == true) {
        this.muted = false;
    } else {
        this.muted = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Show your HTML.

Comment: i just added html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".video").click(function() {
var currentVideo = this;
    if (this.muted) {
        this.muted = false;
        // Loop through all video available
        $(".video").each(function(e){
            if(this!=currentVideo){ // If not current div then mute all other
                this.muted = true;
            }
        });
    } else {
        this.muted = true;
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pr77pn1f/)

Comment: hm seems it does not work for me still sound is being played on one vid while clicked on another